# In what ways the three temperatures are the same

Tags: temperature

In what ways are the three temperatures(Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit) scales the same? In what ways are they different?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: What would you like to know that isn't given on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

All three scales are realted  by equations of the form $T=aT'+b$ for different constants $a$ and $b$. The same is true of the Rankine and Reaumur scales.  That there are many scales in use is just an accident of history.